# How can I add a click event to the v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to call the editItem function  when the table row is clicked. Current what happens is I click on the table row and it doesn't display the details page. Yet when I put this click event on a particular table data the editItem function gets called. How can I make this same function to be called on the table row itself?

Here in my code I have tried using the the v-data-table template and slot and included the click event on the row but it is not working either

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
   <tr @click="editItem(item), selected = item.id">
      <td>{{ props.item.member }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[1] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[2] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[3] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[4] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[5] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[6] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[7] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[8] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[9] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[10] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[11] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[12] }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item[13] }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

I expect that when the row is clicked, the editItem function is called

Comment: This solves your issue: https://codepen.io/nsiggel/pen/KRdGgE

Comment: I actually got the idea in my sample code from here first but it seems not to work on my end. If you notice our templates are quite similar although I had missed this 
@click="editItem(props.item) but even after adding it mine is not working

Comment: I have tried running that same code here <  codepen.io/nsiggel/pen/KRdGgE > on my app and the event is still not working here. Could it be a vuetify version issue?

Comment: Could you make a codepen example where your problem can be reproduced?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 81):

I found a way around it using `@click:row`

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1" @click:row="handleClick">
</v-data-table>
```

The `handleClick` function returns a value of the clicked item so I call the method I want to act upon the value within the `handleClick` method. I also manually highlighted the clicked row since I didn't find a Vuetify way of doing so.

An example of the handleClick method is here:

```
handleClick(value) {
    this.highlightClickedRow(value);
    this.viewDetails(value);
},
```

You can also access the clicked row using event.target. Example is here

```
highlightClickedRow(value) {
    const tr = value.target.parentNode;
    tr.classList.add('highlight');
},
```

Comment: `highlightClickedRow(value)` should be `highlightClickedRow(event)` or the second line `let tr = event.target.parentNode;` should be  `let tr = value.target.parentNode;`

Comment: @SimonThiel How can I get the event object to highlightClickedRow(event). I am getting "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined" error while accessing target from event obj. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If anyone is interested to see the working example, below is the link.
https://codepen.io/mshrestha/pen/VwavGQa

Answer (score 11):

I got another solution with highlighting.
Because Anjayluh's idea was not working for me.

*in Vuetify 2.0.0*

**template**

```
<v-data-table 
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :class="[item.selected && 'selected']"
  @click:row="handleClick"
/>
...
</v-data-table>
```

and the **script method**

```
handleClick(row) {
    // set active row and deselect others
    this.desserts.map((item, index) => {
        item.selected = item === row

        this.$set(this.desserts, index, item)
    })

    // or just do something with your current clicked row item data
    console.log(row.sugar)
},
```

and a **style**

```
.selected {
    background-color: red
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Vuetify 3:**

```html
<v-data-table :items="items" @click:row="handleClick">
```

```js
function handleClick(event, row) {
  console.log("Clicked item: ", row.item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solutions is the best for, maybe help you, it's work with vuetify 2.x.

```
{
  // inside Vue Component
  methods: {
    openLink(link) {
      console.log(`opened link ${link}`)
    }
  }
}

<v-data-table
  :options="{ openLink }"
>
  <template v-slot:body="{ items, options }">
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.id"
      >
        <td>
          <button @click="() => options.openLink(item)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Look: [Data Table Api - slots.body](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#api) it is for me, the best approachable to solve this problem.

Comment: This approach tampers with the responsiveness of the table on the different viewports since you are overriding the default styles. You can go with this if you a) Don't mind about the page responsiveness or b) are willing to design your own responsive styles as a result

Comment: of course ? i'm used in publish product, and not have any issue with this approach.